# Need advice on unit testing with suppressing submethods and constructors

Tags: java, mockito

I have some weird code like this

```
B param = ...;

D main(){
    return A.method(param, C.class, new String[]{"abc"}, new SomeClass()).get(); 
}
```

where

```
public static A method(...)
public D get()
```

How can I mock method main() to suppress submethods invocations and suppress constructing of objects?

I need to mock result of `get()`

Comment: As far as I know, Java doesn't allow to "inline" method calls. You can of course modify the code yourself. But a compiler cannot automatically rewrite code using compiler directives.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from a better designed method that injects instances into the method instead of create them, you can use Powermock to mock constructor calls so the calls to new will actually create mock objects.

here is powermock's tutorial on mock constructors with mockitto

http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13

IN your test you will be able to say:

```
SomeClass myMock = mock(SomeClass.class);
whenNew(SomeClass.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(myMock)
```

Comment: But method `method` is static.

Comment: I don't think it matters if you are mocking the call to `new SomeClass` since that happens before the call to the static method.  However, powermock can work with statics as well please read the powermock tutorial I linked to so you can see how.

Comment: For me it's doesn't work because constructor A is invokated and I got NPE.